how to correctly load and save tf-official models
I am trying to save and load the  trained model from this tutorial > https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/movinet
This is the code from the tutorial in brief :
def build_classifier(batch_size, num_frames, resolution, backbone, num_classes):
  """Builds a classifier on top of a backbone model."""
  model = movinet_model.MovinetClassifier(
      backbone=backbone,
      num_classes=num_classes)
  model.build([batch_size, num_frames, resolution, resolution, 3])
  return model

model = build_classifier(batch_size, num_frames, resolution, backbone, 7)
num_epochs = 30
loss_obj = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)

model.compile(loss=loss_obj, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
results = model.fit(train_ds,
                    validation_data=val_ds,
                    epochs=num_epochs,
                    validation_freq=1,
                    verbose=1)

The following code is what I tried to do :
model.save("./saved_model1")
model = tf.keras.layers.TFSMLayer('./saved_model1', call_endpoint='serving_default')
model.evaluate(test_ds, return_dict=True)

The error :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[86], line 1
----> 1 model.evaluate(test_ds, return_dict=True)

AttributeError: 'TFSMLayer' object has no attribute 'evaluate'


Tried saving the models as .keras , .h5

model.save('my_model.keras')
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("my_model.keras", custom_objects={'MovinetClassifier': movinet_model.MovinetClassifier})
model.evaluate(test_ds, return_dict=True)



and got this error :

--------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 3
      1 model_path= "my_movinet_model2.keras"
      2 # loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
----> 3 loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects={'MovinetClassifier': movinet_model.MovinetClassifier})
      4 model.evaluate(test_ds, return_dict=True)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/saving/saving_api.py:176, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    173         is_keras_zip = True
  
  ..................................... 

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/official/projects/movinet/modeling/movinet_model.py:78, in MovinetClassifier.__init__(self, backbone, num_classes, input_specs, activation, dropout_rate, kernel_initializer, kernel_regularizer, bias_regularizer, output_states, **kwargs)
     75 self._output_states = output_states
     77 state_specs = None
---> 78 if backbone.use_external_states:
     79   state_specs = backbone.initial_state_specs(
     80       input_shape=input_specs['image'].shape)
     82 inputs, outputs = self._build_network(
     83     backbone, input_specs, state_specs=state_specs)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'use_external_states ```
 
The traceback is long to be included . I am unsure of how to load and evaluate the saved model  correctly just like the tutorial . 


It seems like you are encountering several issues when trying to save and load your Movinet model, especially with custom objects and their attributes. Let's break down the steps to save, load, and evaluate the model correctly.When saving the model, it's crucial to use the correct method based on the version of TensorFlow you are using. Since you are using TensorFlow 2.x, model.save() and tf.keras.models.load_model() are appropriate methods.{# Save the model
model.save('my_model')
Optionally, save as .h5 format
model.save('my_model.h5')
}
